# spring freezes after number of frequent refresh / ajax calls

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a spring application that seems to work fine, aside from the fact that after 5-6 requests, it halts and fails to handle any new incoming requests.

My page has a select dropdown, and onChange of that dropdown, makes an ajax call to the spring server. After about 5 or 6 of these, no more are accepted, and refreshing the page hangs indefinitely.

Any idea what may be causing this? Let me know if you need more information as far as configuration files and the like, but I was hoping this was a common enough problem where I could be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks

EDIT

here is my ajax code called onChange

```
$.ajax({
            url: "./service.go?data="+data+",
            dataType:"json",
            timeout:15000,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                ...
            },
            error: function(request,cause,data){
                if (cause ==="timeout"){
                          alert("Request timed out!");
                }
                else{
                          alert("ERROR: " + data.responseText);
                }
            }

        });
```

However, I don't think this is the issue, because even if i dont use ajax at all and jus hit refresh over and over in the browser, it fails.

With further testing, the problem does not occur when i hit a mapping that doesn't require database connectivity, so maybe it has something to do with my hibernate pool configuration? if I refresh a page that requires database connectivity the problem occurs on the 10th request, consistently. Here is my hibernate c3p0 configuration

```
driverClassName=com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
url=jdbc:    HIDDEN
username= 
password= 
# Number of Connections a pool will try to acquire upon startup
initialPoolSize=5
# Minimum number of Connections a pool will maintain at any given time
minPoolSize=1
# Maximum number of Connections a pool will maintain at any given time
maxPoolSize=20
# Connections to acquire when the pool is exhausted
acquireIncrement=5
# Seconds a Connection can remain pooled but unused before being discarded. 30 Min Check
maxIdleTime=1800
#Test all idle, pooled but unchecked-out connections, every this number of seconds
idleConnectionTestPeriod=300
```

and using these properties i define my pool bean as follows

```
<bean id="dsrc" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />

        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${initialPoolSize}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${maxIdleTime}" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />
    </bean>
```

Here is the simple function in my controller that is hit, until he 10th time

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/test")
public @ResponseBody String test(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
    //List<Object> objects = objectService.getObjects(station); // calls hibernate DAO and when this is used instead of system.out, halts after 10th call.
    return "";

}
```

So I know it is hitting the controller due to the printout, until the 10th time. I am unsure of how to tell thereafter if the request is hitting the server since I know at the least the mapping is not hit.

Comment: Are there any server errors being logged that you can provide?

Comment: I am not seeing any error printouts :/

Comment: How do you make those AJAX requests to the Spring, using JSON? If yes, how?

Comment: Can you post the code that is being called during your dropdown's _onChange_ event? Maybe you can give a brief summary of what you see in your browser console Network tab when the AJAX request is fired (although if it is just hanging I'm imagining it will just constantly say "pending request").

Comment: edited post with more info, and es network info just says pending.

Comment: Please provide server-side Java code that is being called. Also, have you tried debugging the server to see if your code is even being hit after 10th time?

Answer (score 2):

Probably something is wrong with your db connections handling. Might be they are not being returned to the pool. Make sure that you are closing all your connections.